# QuickSort program reaching maximum recursion limit of 500?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I am working on analysis of sorting algorithms by plotting graphs in MATLAB. Below is my quick sort code. When I run it it is giving this error:

> Maximum recursion limit of `500` reached. Use `set(0,'RecursionLimit', N)`
>   to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space
>   can crash MATLAB and/or your computer. Error in ==> quickSort

Why does this error occur? Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
function [ar] = quickSort(ar, low, high)
    if low < high
        [ar, q] = parti(ar, low, high);
        ar = quickSort(ar, low, q - 1);
        ar = quickSort(ar, q + 1, high);
    end
end

function [ar, i] = parti(ar, p, r)
    x = ar(r);
    i = p - 1;

    for j = p : r
        if ar(j) <= x
            i = i + 1;
            if i ~= j
                tmp = ar(i);
                ar(i) = ar(j);
                ar(j) = tmp;
            end
        end
    end
    i = i + 1;
    tmp = ar(i);
    ar(i) = ar(r);
    ar(r) = tmp;
end
```

I am calling this function using

```
ar = [7,7,3,0,3,1,4,7,5,6]
quickSort(ar, 1, 10)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger by setting breakpoints and/or adding prints for intermediate results?

Comment: yes.At starting of the quickSort function only I added some print statements.But when I call function it's not printing anything. Just giving that recursion limit error.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to learn debugging beyond using print statements, often you can resolve a lot of problems yourself. Start with this [MATLAB help page](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) and give it a try please.

Comment: The reason you may not be getting any print output is that your code is stuck in an infinite recursion. Using **breakpoints and single-stepping your code** will easily reveal the problem. (Aside: I am unable to help you with a direct solution as I don't have access to MATLAB right now.)

Comment: @crazyGamer, as you suggested I go throw the debugging process step by step after so many experiments I found that ** in above code parti () function at the end of the function (after swapping ar(i) and ar(r), if I do i=i-1 **  then the problem of recursion limit exceed problem solved. But here are two problems again. 1.It is not giving sorted output for all input data. and second problem, very strange one that for same input(same number of elements in list) sometimes code running and giving coorect/ wrong answer, BUT sometimes giving index out of bound exception.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to debug the code. I have found the bug, and am working out the solution now.

Comment: Why are you using `low` and `high`, when quicksort just requires a single pivoting index?

Comment: You need a low and high after you partition the array, to specify if it is the lower half or the upper half from the pivot. This is similar to C like implementations as I understand.

Comment: This isn't C though, and it would be much easier (and faster) to use MATLAB's logical indexing based on some pivot element, scrapping `parti` all together! See my answer :)

Comment: Thata true, but do note that it is *only* faster due to MATLAB's powerful vectorization for library functions. In reality, you are doing multiple iterations on the array and also reallocating it, while the original algorithm is in-place and fastest. *I do like your solution*, but I assumed the OP is trying to *learn* by this activity than create a usable library.

Comment: Yeah that's why I've tried to explain my answer too, in fairness I've run a couple of tests and I think your fix + the original code is quicker than mine, the code is just less MATLAB-esque!

Comment: @crazyGamer great observation and Wolfie nice explanation. You discussed that, we can write more efficient code in Matlab. Of course but I need every intermediate list. Because I am working on variants of quick sort. When I found the behaviour of an intermediate list (if the small number of elements) then instead of going through recursive call I will use another sorting technique which works faster for smaller input. I am not saying this is the perfect way for working on variants of quick sort. But my idea is this. Suggest me if any better you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function `parti`, to partition the array based on the pivot, you are *including the pivot itself* when trying to determining it's correct position.

This is leading in an infinite recursion in some cases, as the **pivot just keeps swapping between adjacent locations, as it is *comparing with itself***.

### Two solutions:

#### Solution 1:

```
function [ar,i]= parti(ar,p,r)
    x=ar(r);
    i=p-1;

    for j=p:r-1 % Notice the r-1
        if ar(j) <= x
            i=i+1;
            if i~=j
    % ...
```

#### Solution 2:

```
function [ar,i]= parti(ar,p,r)
    x=ar(r);
    i=p-1;

    for j=p:r
        if ar(j) < x % Notice the change in checking
            i=i+1;
            if i~=j
    % ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gone into some depth here about optimising your use of MATLAB, how you should better leverage recursive functions and a redraft of your code. **To skip to the working redraft of a quicksort function, see the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> code blocks below**

---

It isn't helping that in your function you're using `low` and `high` indices to keep track of your partitioning. The whole point of using a recursive quick sort function is this:

1. Pick a pivot element `ar(p)` from the array `ar`
2. Split into 2 arrays, one with values less than `ar(p)` and one with values greater than `ar(p)`. Equal values can go in either array, as they will remain next to the pivot.
3. Return to step 1. with each list, repeat.

The lists are self-similar, by which I mean **treat each sub-list as its own list which needs sorting, not part of a larger list**! You don't need to keep track of indices (which end up confusing when you're 3 recursions deep), just analyse each list on its own.

You may find the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) useful as it details these 3 points, as well as suggesting some schemes for optimally picking the pivot. In the below code, I just choose the middle element.

---

Additionally, your partitioning function `parti` is *really* inefficient. In MATLAB, if you find yourself looping through every index of an array then you could probably speed things up. Instead, vectorize your code using logical indexing!

At the very least, learn some more about indexing in the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) because you can do neat things like this:

```
% Your code for swapping array elements
tmp = arr(i);
ar(i) = ar(r);
ar(r) = tmp;
% Using MATLAB's indexing
ar([i,r]) = ar([r,i]);
```

*Edit: Although this demonstrates a more "MATLAB-esque" way of doing things, [you incur a performance hit assigning elements like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502261/performance-of-swapping-two-elements-in-matlab), so if you don't mind longer code then feel free to use temps!*

---

You can replace all of your code with this 7 line function, which will be much quicker. I've added comments to explain the logic...

```
function ar = qs(ar)
% Quicksort algorithm, for some 1D array "ar"
% First check we have more than one element, vital to terminate the recursion!
    if numel(ar) > 1
        % Choose some pivot index p, which we will split the array around
        p = ceil(numel(ar)/2);
        % Put values from "ar" which are smaller than "ar(p)" in one array
        smaller = ar(ar < ar(p));
        % Put values from "ar" which are larger than "ar(p)" in another array
        larger = ar(ar > ar(p));
        % Rebuild "ar" from a (qs-sorted) array of the smaller elemenets, then all
        % elements which were equal the pivot element (no need to sort these!) then 
        % a (qs-sorted) array of the larger elements.
        ar = [qs(smaller), ar(ar == ar(p)), qs(larger)];    
    end
end
```

This can be run as in your test:

```
ar = [7,7,3,0,3,1,4,7,5,6];
qs(ar)
>> ans = [0 1 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 7]
```

---

We could make this even shorter by not explicitly declaring `smaller` and `larger`, as well as always choosing `p=1` (although  that is the worst case for already sorted arrays).

```
function ar = qs(ar)
    if numel(ar) > 1
        ar = [qs(ar(ar < ar(1))), ar(ar == ar(1)), qs(ar(ar > ar(1)))];    
    end
end
```